# Differences between versions of "Nerves", by Lester del Rey

Tags: novel, short-stories, lester-del-rey

In 1942, Lester del Rey published *Nerves*, a novella about an accident at an atomic plant; in 1956 he published a new version of it, expanded to a novel. I read those two.

According to the [ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22335), there is a 1976, slightly revised, version of the novel. Does anybody know more about the differences between the 1956 and 1976 version, especially regarding the verisimilitude of scientific and technical details?

Comment: (What was wrong with "as regards..."?)

Comment: @Kevin agreed with DaG as it should either be "with regard to" or "as regards" or even just "regarding" but the current phrasing is just awkward. See [in regard or regards](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46917/in-regard-to-or-in-regards-to) or [regard, regards, regarding](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/which-is-correct-with-regards-to-in-regards-with-regarding).

Answer (score 2):

The most recent version was revised slightly in 1976.  Del Rey himself wrote “In planning a sixth printing, the publisher has kindly permitted me to go over it again. A third of a century has passed since I first wrote the story, and I can look at it far more objectively. So again I've revised it slightly, eliminating inconsistencies, expanding a bit for clarity, - but essentially leaving the story as it was always meant to be.” (source the Historical Note appendix found in the 1976 Ballantine edition.)